# How do I put several <div>s in the middle of my webpage with css?

Tags: css

I'm not sure how to ask it.  I want to create a webpage that has top, left, right or close, but I mainly want to know how to put the center content in with divs.  I have attached an image for clarity.[image]

http://demo.xoops-theme.com/?xoops_theme_select=smashingmagazine

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking how to use css/divs to layout the highlighted part. If so here you go:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  .content {
    margin:100px;
  }

  .row {
    clear:both;
  }
  .half {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
  }
  /* This is used to manage the desired padding without affecting the size of .half */
  .inner {
    padding:20px;
  }

</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="half">
        <div class="inner">
          <h4>The Title</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
          cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
          proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="half">
        <div class="inner">
          <h4>The Title</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
          cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
          proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="full">
        <div class="inner">
          <h4>The Title</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
          cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
          proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="half">
        <div class="inner">
          <h4>The Title</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
          cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
          proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="half">
        <div class="inner">
          <h4>The Title</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
          cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
          proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```